# @media screen? cant move down boxes?

Tags: jquery, html, css

ok two problems... how do I take away the scroll bar when the screen gets smaller and why can't I move the boxes down? as you can see from the code at the bottom the scroll bar is still there for no reason and the buttons won't move even with padding! I appreciate anything you can suggest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/Metro-M.svg/2000px-Metro-M.svg.png">
<head>
<style>
body {
  background: URL("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lYQ3vQHE3Mo/VrVKGwg8pqI/AAAAAAAADMQ/QKjs5ALViKo/w530-d-h253-p-rw/desk%2Bbackground.png") white no-repeat center top;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h2 {
Font-family: Arial;
top: 650px;
left: 10px;
position: absolute;
color: #525252;
font-size: 2vw;
letter-spacing: 1px;

}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21%;
  left: 36%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 4.6vw;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  top: 800px;
  left: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
color:#696969;
font-size: 17px;
}
ul {
  word-spacing: .2em;
  letter-spacing: .2em;
}
ul li {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  top: 43%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-left: 115px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: normal;
  background-color: rgba(5, 4, 2, 0.1);
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 90%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
}
ul li:link,
ul li:visited {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-left: 115px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: normal;
  background-color: rgba(5, 4, 2, 0.1);
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-size: 90%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
li {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
ul li:hover,
ul li:active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover, ul li a:active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}  

ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
hr {
margin-right: 150px;
margin-left: 150px;
top: 700px;

}


@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

  .wrapper {
    padding-top: 40%;
  }

  ul li {
    margin: 10px;

  }
  h1{
    position:absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 180px;
    font-size
 }
}
.wrapper {
  padding-top: 0%;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about.css">
<title>morgan</title>

</head>
<body>
<center><h1>WHO AM I?</h1></center>
<h2>Some Fun Facts</h2>

<p>I made this website from scratch when I was 14, I have a twin brother whose name is Pierson McNeal White, I have a older brother and sister who are aslo twins, I used to have 2 pet rats named Hermes and Cleo after the greek gods, and I watch the super bowl for the ads.</p> 
<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
<li><a href="www.youtube.com" class="life" ><strong>MY LIFE</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="www.youtube.com" class="prot"><strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="www.youtube.com" class="resume"><strong>RESUME</strong></a></li>
<li><a href="about.html" class="me"><strong>ABOUT ME</strong></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar is not disappearing because the 'p' element has its position set to absolute. As well as a 'left' value of 300px.

This means the element will stay with a width of 600px and a left value of 300px, effectively making it 900px wide even when the window size is smaller.